# How can I force R to pick all the levels in a variables while running the CLMM

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3C1n.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ucJy.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0n7s.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53Bvq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vetHa.png)

I'm very new to R and running a CLMM for my Ph.D. thesis. It's an experimental design where I have four conditions with 48 items with two levels "SUB" and "IND".
I collected the data on a 4-point Likert scale and now I want to see which respondents chose which items with which level(SUB or IND). I want to study the effects of Meta and English/Spanish Proficiency scores on the response variable. For the same purpose, First, I ran a null model with the following:

modnull236<-clmm(response ~  (1|Id) +(1|item), data=Mainhd, link="probit")

After that, I started adding independent variable of my interest one by one(Meta score, English Prof, Spanish Prof).

Now these are the three main problems I have:

1-After adding English proficiency score I'm getting "Nan error"(attached the screenshot). I tried to remove the random effect (Item) and it worked, but I'm not sure if that's the right way to do it.

2-It's quite strange that R is not picking level "IND" while running the model. PS. I've already used the relevel function, but it doesn't work.

3-Also, can someone explain to me what exactly is a pairwise comparison? I have 90 participants and they have done the same task for Hindi and Spanish languages and I need to run the post hoc after fitting the model. I would appreciate some guidance as I'm very new to stats and I've learned everything from Youtube and reading several blogs. My apologies if there are things that don't make any sense. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePOfa.png)

Comment: Could you edit your question to include some code, reproducible data, and expected output?

Comment: I edited it, thanks.

Comment: But you didn’t edit to include any of the things that were requested - again could you edit to include reproducible data and expected output?

Comment: Can't answer (1) without a reproducible example. (2) is happening because of the way that R codes factors (and more generally how factors *must* be coded in a linear model); I've posted a few answers about this over the years, it is mentioned in passing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76204028/how-to-draw-significant-coefficients-against-log-odds-incidence-rate-ratio-for/76205437#76205437) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337761/linear-regression-na-estimate-just-for-last-coefficient/7341074#7341074). (3) That's a question for https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: If anyone else has a canonical reference for the "why is my output missing a level of the factor", please point to it ...

Comment: This is the command I used to run the model: modnull000<-clmm(response ~ referend*level*Elextale + (1|Id) + (1|item), data=Mainsd, link="probit") I've already attached the image of the error along with my dataset.

Comment: Voting to close this as "needing focus" -- there are 3 separate questions here ((1) "why NaN in this case?"; (2) "why missing levels of the factor in the output?"; (3) "what is a pairwise comparison?"); furthermore you still haven't given us a **reproducible** example, e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example ...  Also (sorry to pile on the requests), please post your data example/code/outputs as **text** (in a code block), not images: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors